# Is there a program that will show a tree of the differences in two file trees?

Tags: filesystems, diff, data-transfer, tree

In windows I manually back up from time to time by formatting my external drive and copying the contents of my data partition over. Inevitably there is a difference in the number and size of the files copied because of system files, etc.

Is there a program that would `diff` two directories recursively and compile the differences into a nice GUI tree that I could peruse (preferably filter) to ensure that everything I want made it over to the drive? It should only show files that are not in both directories.

(Also, please ignore the inadequacy of my backup solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WinMerge](http://manual.winmerge.org/Compare_dirs.html) should be able to do what you require.
I've used it for comparing files, but not folders. The file comparison section is great, and I imagine that the folder part is similar.

[image]

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned this was a very large backup (~1TB). I did use WinMerge but I had to leave it go overnight and check the results the next day.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [git](http://git-scm.com/) to do this with directories A and B:

```
$ cd A/
$ git init && git add . && git commit -am"first version of A (or any other commit message)"
$ cd ../B/
$ git init && git add . && git commit -am"first version of B (or any other commit message)"
$ git fetch ../A/ && git diff FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: I wouldn't even begin to attempt to read that without code formatting.   Indent each line by four spaces and leave a blank line above it.

Comment: Sorry! Fixed that.

Comment: Revisting this question. I actually like this solution more now than I originally did. I think this would work a lot better for smaller backups however, as multi-TB git repos are rather unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't meet your specification exactly, but `Robocopy` is part of a standard win Vista/7/8 install (and part of the windows resource kit for pre-vista). It is command line, but can be used to synchronize locations, and can also be set to monitor the source for changes and rerun a job.

It has extensive options and also has a LOG only switch for you to examine the output further.

ROBOCOPY /? will give you all options.

Comment: Was aware of RoboCopy. I don't really want the extra system files copied, I just want to ensure that nothing important was left behind.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I'd like to mention Beyond Compare here (paid, Scooter Software). Personally I think it's user friendlier than WinMerge. If you use this folder comparison feature often, it's well worth the money. I don't remember if WinMerge supports this, but you can compare over FTP too.